# proper way to use ngif that rely on a async function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

i have a `navbar` that gets initialized in the `app.comonent.html`

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container">
  <flash-messages></flash-messages>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

in the `navbar` i have some buttons that should only be showing if user is logged in (logout, dashboard etc)

so i have some `ng if`'s but i cant get it to work.

i tried calling the async function that returns true or false within the `ng if`

*is loggedIn function from service:*

```
loggedIn() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/validateToken')
      .map(res => res.json()).map(data => data.success);
  }
```

*navbar:*

```
<li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()">
```

also tried adding `| async`

and i tried setting a variable `onInit` that asserts a variable to true or false, and then let the `ngIf` use the variable instead.

but it doesn't update that way, and just get stuck on false.

how can i tackle this ?

Comment: If you want to do that, your `authService` should be declared as `public` when you inject it into your constructor. is that the case already ?

Comment: i tried with both, no success